# If an async Vuex action is run twice, can the code following the await call be run in random order?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vuex, race-condition

```js
const actions = {
  search: debounce(
    async ({ commit, dispatch, getters, rootGetters }, { page = 1 }) => {
      commit("setLoading", true);
      commit("setPage", page);

      console.log("Starting...")
      const randId = Math.random() * 100;
      console.log(randId);

      const results = await EventApi.get();

      console.log("Done: ", randId, `|${results.meta.slept}|`)

      // After `await`
      commit(page == 1 ? "setEvents" : "addEvents", results.events);
      // ... and a bunch more commits after that.

    }, 300, { leading: true, trailing: true })
  }
}
```

If the action above is called twice:

```
store.dispatch('search', { page: 1 });
store.dispatch('search', { page: 1 });
```

Let's assume the request made by the first call takes 10s to complete, and the request made by the second one takes only 1 second.

Is the code after `await EventApi.get()` in the **second call** executed **after** the one in the **first call**, even thought the request should have finished way earlier? I wouldn't have thought so but my experiment showed that it was the case, so something must be wrong with my code.

Here are the Vuex logs + some of my comments:

https://gist.github.com/niuage/9e2dcd509dc6d5246b3a16af56ccb3d3

---

In case it helps, here's the simplified EventApi module:

```js
const get = async () => {
  const q = await fetch(someUrl);
  const result = await q.json();

  return result;
}

export default {
  get
}
```

I'm asking because I'm having an issue where, super rarely, I get my result count out of sync with the results actually displayed, so I was guessing that it could be because there was a race condition between multiple requests.

Comment: Yes, code after an `await` can run at any future point in time, and when multiple things are waiting for different promises, they might run in any order. Nothing in your code instructs the second call to wait for the result of the first one.

Comment: And if it *is* "super rarely," its kinda up to you whether it's actually critical to fix it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second, shorter, call in your example would complete first.  This is because the `await` only waits within the context of the `async` function.

Since `async/await` is a different way of writing promises, you can think of it as 2 separate function calls that return a promise.  The one would not delay the other.

Here's a demo:

```js
const delay = time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), time))

async function wait(id, time) {
  await delay(time);
  console.log(id + ' complete.');
}

console.log('Starting 1...');
wait('#1', 5000);
console.log('Starting 2...');
wait('#2', 1000);
```

```html
View the bottom portion of the demo for the console results.
```

Here's the `async` function from the demo above written with `.then` instead:

```js
function wait(id, time) {
  return delay(time).then(() => {
    console.log(id + ' complete.');
  });
}
```

---

If you wanted to force the second function call in your example to wait for the first, make the calling context of both an `async` function, for example:

```js
async created() {
  // Assuming the `search` action returns its http promise!
  await this.$store.dispatch('search', { page: 1 });
  await this.$store.dispatch('search', { page: 1 });
  ...
}
```

Comment: See, that's what I thought, so I'm glad you confirmed it, but that means there's something else wrong with my code. I added a `sleep(15)` in the api end point that runs once every 2 requests. I make the first one, then the second one, and the second one resolves only after the first one did... Take a look at this debug log from vuex + my own comments: https://gist.github.com/niuage/9e2dcd509dc6d5246b3a16af56ccb3d3.

Comment: Well now that I answered your question you changed it so that my answer looks pointless :)  I guess I can still check out your 2nd question...

Comment: What does "`sleep` on the backend" mean?

Comment: I rephased it at the end and added the github gist. I left "Am I correct when I say that the code after" so I don't think your answer changes at all. It's the same issue as before, but the cause might different than what I guessed first :)

Comment: The sleep fakes a long request. The server will take a super long time to return a response. It's a ruby "sleep" statement.

Comment: Hm I'm not familiar with Ruby so I could only guess that maybe it's sleeping the entire backend.  Beyond that, I would use the second part of my answer if you need to force an order to your responses

Comment: I can't really use that solution as that request can be fired from several components, at random times, triggered by actions from the user. That being said, you might be right, and the experiment might be flawed if the second request is also affected by the sleep.
Thanks, the confirmation that I wasn't misunderstanding anything about async/await is mainly what I was looking for.
I'll look into implementing some kind of simple queue to solve my concurrency issue.

Comment: No worries.  One option then would be to queue up requests like an array of requests to perform.  Once a request finishes, you remove it from the queue and check for another.  Oh nevermind, you just said that.

Comment: I'm glad you thought about the same thing :)